# Laravel - Limit a routegroup to one user at a time?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way to limit all routes within a group to one user at a time. In practice, this translates to an admin control panel that only one admin can use at a time. Any number can be logged into the web app at any given point, but if one enters the control panel, it should lock the others out until he returns to the regular client website.

I'm running laravel 5.2.9

Comment: Re-think about your solution. this is a wrong way of protection. why you want to do such limitation?

Comment: Seems database flag would be a solution out. I have not thought about issues that may arise from this though. But I think also if the admin refuses to logout, then others will never be able to login.

Comment: This is a limitation imposed on the webapp. I wouldn't do this if I didn't have to.


As for the DB solution, I thought of that, but I ran against the same limitations. Perhaps give the actual sessions a very short timeout, so if an admin doesn't log out/idles on one page, it will allow someone new to, metaphorically, "take" the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you asked and forced all users to Logout after leaving the Admin Panel

Then it will be so easy:

- After login add a flag in Database
- Then add a middleware to Route::group when flag exists don't allow others
- After logout, remove the flag

Answer (score 0):

Once you want to let all users login to the system, so limiting the session timeout is not the solution.

You can do as following:

1. Store last user and the access timestamp to larval Cache or DB each time a user visits admin page
2. Before allow a user to enter admin page, check the stored user and its last access from Cache/DB. If no data was stored (first access) or it was expired (max idle time after user's last access) or it was the same user, then let him in.
3. This way if current admin stay idle and someone else took the page, then current admin will be redirected to normal area on his next action.